# How to print image using loop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]I am trying to print my image in react that i get by user. Image gets converted to base64 and i want to convert it to jpg, png or gif according to type by user which was orignally the format when user submits. I want that new image gets added to part of react website and the old image should not get replaced. Can anyone please tell how to print it?

Fileupload.js:

```
const saveImage = () => {
  axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/image",{
    imgName: window.bs64,
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  const getImage = () => {
      console.log('getImage');
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
          setImage(result);
          console.log(result);
          for(let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
//             const Example = ({ result.data[i] }) => <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${result.data[i]}`} />
//             ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data} />, document.getElementById('container'))
        }
      });
  }

  getImage();
}, []);



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          uploadImage(e);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={saveImage}>Save</button>
      <br/>
</div>
  );
}

export default File;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that you recieve the images as an Array.

in the useEffect you assign:

```
 const [arrayImages,setArrayImages] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
   const getImage = () => {
        console.log('getImage');
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
              setArrayImages(result.data);
          });
      }

  getImage();
}, []);
```

and then inside your return:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          uploadImage(e);
        }}/> 
{arrayImages.map(image =>
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`}/>
);}
      <button onClick={saveImage}>Save</button>
      <br/>
</div>
  );
```

Comment: It gives this error: ./src/Fileupload.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "..." (57:2)

  55 |           uploadImage(e);
  56 |         }}
> 57 | {arrayImages.map(image =>
     |  ^
  58 | <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`}/>
  59 | );}
  60 |       <button onClick={saveImage}>Save</button>

Comment: please add a screenshot

Comment: Added please check now

Comment: I edited my code, there was missing  a '/>'

Comment: I need to fetch image from database

Comment: It helped me solve my answer a bit. So thank you for telling me this